# Logic level of CP2102

Tags: uart, logic-level

I want to have an USB-UART interface for my Controller. I was thinking to use CP2102 and thus was reading the data sheet. But I cannot figure out the logic level of the UART part of CP2102. Can you someone please direct me to the proper section of the datasheet that says about this? BTW, the logic level of my Controller UART interface is 2.8V

Answer (score 3):

On page 8 of the datasheet VOH is referenced to VDD. So the outputs can swing between 0 and VDD. VDD can be between 3.0 and 3.6V. See VIL and VIH for input levels.

Comment: Thank you for the information. As my Controller UART interface is 2.8V, therefore I need to use a level shifter or simple voltage divider, right? When I calculate resistance for voltage divider, shall I calculate the logic level of CP2102 as 3.3V?